# Following along with a 'blog tutorial' but npm run dev not working for me

Tags: npm

Following along with a 'blog tutorial' but npm run dev not working for me.

Terminal:

```
candicetomkins@Candys-Air ~/Desktop/cms-blog $ npm run dev                                       [ruby-2.6.8p205]
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/candicetomkins/.npm/_logs/2022-06-27T15_49_33_958Z-debug-0.log
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.35",
    "@types/react": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.2",
    "typescript": "4.7.2"
  }
  
}
```

What have I missed here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your NPM version. It should be because of version mismatched issue. Make sure your nodeJS and NPM version be updated